# How to add 2 Decimal Value by Default

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, decimal

I am doing a Currency Calculator in C#, I have some text boxes to enter data. but my problem is when i enter first Digit it should entered in to decimal like 0.02 and when i enter 5 as a 2nd Digit it should enter as 0.25 as like following 
i tried this following code it gets me an error. 
1st digit = 2 result 0.02, 2nd digit = 5 result 0.25, 3rd digit = 8 result 2.58
typically like entering value into ATM Machine. how can i do that
I have tried this following code it gets me an error. String is not in correct format

```
TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: sounds like you could just use a [Masked TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx)

Comment: @Jonesy: and the mask that does what the OP asks is .... ?

Answer (score 1):

When you enter "2", it is parsed as the number 2 so it is formatting correctly. Try dividing the parsed value based on the length of the string for the first 2 digits entered.

```
double Value = 0;

if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out Value)) {
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1) {
        Value /= 10;
    } else if (textBox1.Text.Length == 2) {
        Value /= 100;
    }

    TextBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", Value);

}
```

Comment: This...this is not C#. :(

Comment: :) no worries I figure you would